# Is a suit of armor considered one thing with respect to enchanting it?

Tags: magic-items, armor, ars-magica-5

Would each piece of a suit of armor have to be enchanted separately (let's say I wanted to lighten the armor), or could it be enchanted as a whole?

I'd like to be able to do it as a whole, but there's some controversy in our group.

In the shape and materials table, one of the items that is listed is "boots".  Implying that the pair would be taken as a whole, or one item.

Answer (score 5):

This may not be as thorough an answer as one might hope for, but I forwarded this question to Atlas Games, and got this reply from Cam Banks, the RPG Director there:

> Good question! I believe the intent is that you treat the whole armor
>   suit as one item. You may get different answers based on whom you ask
>   over at the forums at www.atlas-games.com however.
>   --Cam

So, [I then asked the question on their official forums](http://forum.atlas-games.com/viewtopic.php?f=4&t=32862&p=272741#p272741) and got no consistent reply (yet, although more replies may come), and no specific books cited as sources.  One answered with a question, another answered with "It depends on whatever your game master wants to do", and another said that there are too many books to tell definitively.

Still, I think that an email from the RPG Director of the company might count as a definitive source.  Hopefully this helps.

Answer (score -3):

I would do it as a whole if it is a suit of normal armor. However, if there are already enchantments on it and your storyteller allows more to be added, then I would count each item enchanted as a separate thing.

So if for example, you have a suit of plate mail that is mundane you could enchant the whole suit to be lighter, however if you had a plate male suit, and plate gloves of sure grip, you would have to enchant the armor, and then the gloves. Two enchants both paid for...well unless you have a PC that enchants..then that is wicked awesome!

Comment: Hi Matthew, and welcome to RPG Stack  Exchange. Check out our [tour] to see how we work here. This answer would benefit from citations from the rulebooks. The asker is looking for rules guidance *and* trying to settle a controversy in their group -- what one person on the internet "would do" isn't a very credible source unfortunately.